# Setting custom boundary conditions in pdetoode

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

I am solving a mix of PDE and ODE for two functions c1(x,t) and c2(t). Several answer point to the use of the function [pdetoode](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127980/dynamic-euler-bernoulli-beam-equation/127997#127997). 
I would like to use that function, but set the my own boundary conditions, which are of the following  type :

[image: Boundary Conditions]

Any help on how to choose my boundary conditions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome Marc!  Could you add code for a toy problem that shows where you get stuck?

Comment: `pdetoode` can handle this type of b.c. straightforwardly, which part do you have difficulty?